# Add border to active thumbnail in jquery galleria theme

Tags: jquery, galleria

I've been through the CSS and tried adding active states for the thumb and adding the border there to no avail.

Comment: If you setup a JSFiddle of your problem you're more likely to receive good advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.galleria-thumbnails .galleria-image.active img {
  border: solid 1px white;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kyle! I was thisclose but I added a colon before the active and did not have img after that. Thanks for helping me and teaching me something. Now my question is why the border is only showing on the top and the left. Obviously it's a sizing issue. Anymore thoughts? :D

Comment: add `!important` after `white`. Let me know what that does

Comment: It killed the padding above the border for the thumbnail container and still not showing border on right and bottom...lol...

Comment: I'd need more code than this. I suggest accepting this answer then opening another question

Comment: Hey Kyle. Just figured it out! I added padding to all sides in this tag .galleria-thumbnails .galleria-image and that showed the 2 missing sides. Thanks for helping me make this happen!